# Deleting duplicates of a list without touching specified elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose I have a list, for example: `list = {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 2, 4};` and list of duplicates positions in the list `positions = {3, 9};`, that should not be touched by  `DeleteDuplicates`. Other duplicates should be deleted. (the desired result should be

> {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}

Also, the elements defined by positions (for example 5) should not be deleted even if there are many of them in the list. How can this be done in a most efficient way?

Comment: if you have `list={1,2,3,3,4,3}` and `position={3}`, what's your expected output?

Comment: {1,2,3,3,4,3}, shoud remain the same

Comment: @DavidBaghdasaryan What is the expected output for `{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 5, 5, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 2, 4}`? is it `{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 5, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}`?

Comment: It should be `{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 5, 5, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}`

Comment: Thanks for the response. The question does not say that. It says `DeleteDuplicates` should not touch the elements at the given positions. Please include that part in the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be reasonably fast:

```
ClearAll[value];
value[exceptions_List] := value[Alternatives @@ DeleteDuplicates@exceptions];
value[exceptions_][x_] /; MatchQ[x, exceptions] := Unique[];
value[exceptions_][x_] := x;
```

OP's examples:

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 2, 4};
positions = {3, 9};
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, value[list[[positions]]]]
(*  {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}  *)

list = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3};
positions = {3};
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, value[list[[positions]]]]
(*  {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3}  *)
```

---

*Update.* Even faster:

```
ddxc[expr_, exceptions_List] := Module[{value},
   (value[#] := Unique[]) & /@ exceptions;
   value[x_] := x;
   DeleteDuplicatesBy[expr, value]
   ];

SeedRandom[0];
list = RandomInteger[1000, 10^5];
positions = Range[100];
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, value[list[[positions]]]] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
ddxc[list, list[[positions]]] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.661751, 10668}
  {0.136582, 10668}
*)
```

Comment: Friendly heads-up: I just posted an answer that is critical of yours, in case you care to rebut.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
DeleteDuplicates[list, And[#1 == #2, Not@MemberQ[list[[positions]], #1]] &]
```

Answer (score 5):

*Clarifiation:* The performance concern regarding `Unique` appears to no longer apply in recent versions.  The code below still tests faster for me but deprecation of methods using `Unique` is presently unfounded.

---

This question is related to [How to Gather a list with some elements considered unique](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11448/121) and I propose a similar solution to what I offered there.

```
fn1[a_, p_] :=
  Module[{f, x, i = 1},
    Scan[(f[#] := x[i++]) &, p];
    GatherBy[a, f][[All, 1]]
  ]

fn1[{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 2, 4}, {5, 7}]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}
> ```

Compared to Michael's fastest function:

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = RandomInteger[1*^6, 2*^6];
positions = Range[100];

fn1[list, list[[positions]]]  // Length // AbsoluteTiming
ddxc[list, list[[positions]]] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {2.90443, 865482}
>
> {7.5404, 865482}
> ```

Comment: Is there a danger in using `Unique[]`, or is it simply that your way is faster?

Comment: @MichaelE2 IIRC using `Unique` excessively progressively slows the system down as the Symbol table becomes large.  See the timings in my linked answer for an example.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I just ran the referenced example in 10.1.0 and I did not experience the progressive slow-down so I guess that problem has been fixed now?  I guess I don't need to warn against it any longer, but for backward compatibility if nothing else it's good to be aware of the problem in older versions.

Comment: I had considered something like `x[i++]` in place of `Unique[]`, but `Unique[]` *seemed* cleaner.  I didn't think of the non-Temporary attribute of the symbols created.  I get about the midpoint in timing between `ddxc` and `fn1` if I make that change.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I updated both this answer and the older one to clarify the situation as I now observe it.

Comment: Thanks.  BTW, I hope people notice coolwater's answer. I believe it's faster than both of ours.

Comment: @MichaelE2 On my machine with the test above his code is about 40% slower than mine.   Not so for you?

Comment: Ah, it depends on the first argument to `RandomInteger` and `positions` (roughly, the density of the values represented by `positions`).  I tested a different example.  On your example it's quite a bit slower (60%) on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working version.

```
deleteDuplicateRestricted[list_, pos_] := 
 Module[{keptElems = list[[pos]], i = foo}, 
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, 
   If[! MemberQ[keptElems, #], Identity[#], i++] &]]

deleteDuplicateRestricted[{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3}, {3}]
(*{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3}*)

deleteDuplicateRestricted[{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 
  2, 4}, {3, 9}]
(*{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}*)
```

There shouldn't be a symbolic place holder like that `foo` in high quality codes.

Comment: You could replace `foo` by `Unique["foo"]`.  (Also, you could use `#` instead of `Identity[#]`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have tried things like that but it didn't improve the running time. Actually even completely replacing the symbolic placeholder(use 0 as starting index and `i--` instead, since there is no negative numbers in the list ) does not help. Perhaps the bottleneck is somewhere else.

Comment: I just meant it as a response to your remark about `foo` & quality code.  Even `"foo"` might be better as it cannot be assigned a value.  As for speed, I think it's pretty fast, just slightly slower than my first method.  That suggests to me that `MemberQ` is probably the bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

The following method indexes the list and then deletes the duplicates

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 2, 4}; 
positions = {3, 9};
f[x_, pos_] :=
 If[MemberQ[pos, Last@First[#]], #[[;; , 1]], Sequence @@ #[[;; , 1]]] & /@ 
    SplitBy[Transpose[{x, Range@Length[x]}], First] // DeleteDuplicates // Flatten;
f[list, positions]
(*{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}*)
```

The proposed answer works even for the following list:

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 5, 5, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 2, 4};
f[list, positions]
(*{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 5, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}*)
```

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for pointing that out. Please check the edit.

Comment: Now it deletes one of the 3s (in my example).  I get `{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3}` and I think there should be another 3 at the end.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The question says `DeleteDuplicates` should not touch the elements at the given positions. So, for an input of `{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3}` and positions of `{3}`, it should return `{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3}`. This is according to the OP update.

Comment: I disagree: The final two 3s (= the value of the element at position `{3}`) should not be "touched" either, as stated in the OP. But comments are not for such debates.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that up. I read it differently.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4};

p = {3, 9};
```

Using [SequenceCases](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) and [DeleteElements](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteElements.html) (new in 13.1) -
non-competitive timewise for long lists, but short and easy to
understand.

```
c = Complement[SequenceCases[list, {a_, a_} :> a], list[[p]]]
```

{2, 4, 12}

```
n = Lookup[c] @ Counts[list] - 1
```

{1, 3, 1}

```
DeleteElements[list, n -> c]
```

{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}

A oneliner

```
DeleteElements[list, Lookup[#] @ Counts[list] - 1 -> #]& @
 Complement[SequenceCases[list, {a_, a_} :> a], list[[p]]]
```

{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}

Answer (score 1):

There is also this one:

```
 (a = Delete[list, Transpose[{Flatten[Lookup[PositionIndex[list],
   Complement[list, list[[positions]]]][[All, 2 ;;]]]}]];)//Timing

 (b = ddxc[list, list[[positions]]];) // Timing

 a === b
```

> {0.125, Null}
>
> {0.265625, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Nice! (Note that [`Timing` is unreliable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14152/4999) in hyperthreaded environments. I usually use `AbsoluteTiming` or `RepeatedTiming`.)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `Split`:

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 2, 4};

p = {3, 9};

sp = Split[list];
elems = Extract[list, List /@ p];

Catenate[If[! ContainsAny[#, elems], Union@#, #] & /@ sp]

(*{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}*)
```

Or using `Tally`:

```
ta = Tally[list];
rep = {a_, b_} :> Splice@Array[a &, b];

(If[! ContainsAny[#, elems], {#[[1]], 1}, #] & /@ ta) /. rep

(*{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `MapIndexed`:**

The strategy is to convert an entry in `list` either at one of the positions in `p` or an actual entry in the list `p` an interim value, that does not contradict another assigned value. After that run `DeleteDuplicates` and then restore the augmented entry.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[list_List, p_List] := 
 Module[{r1}, 
  r1 = MapIndexed[
    If[MemberQ[p, First@#2] || MemberQ[list[[p]], #1], {#1, 
       First@#2}, #] &, list];
  DeleteDuplicates[r1] /. {a_, b_} :> a
  ]
```

---

*Usage:**

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 2, 4};
p = {3, 9};
f[list, p]
```

> {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4}

---

Compare with above where the the two added entries at the end are also protected:

```
list = {1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7};
p = {3, 9};
f[list, p]
```

{1, 3, 5, 5, 12, 6, 11, 7, 7, 9, 10, 2, 4, 5, 7}

---

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3};
p = {3};
f[list, p]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3}