# Do not combine certain elements in Split or SplitBy

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Let's say I have the following list:

```
list = 
  {{"Text", "hello", "a"}, {"Text", " world", "a"}, {"TextElement", "line", "a"}, 
   {"TextElement", "line", "a"}, {"Text", "!", "b"}, {"Text", "ok", "c"}}
```

I want to to combine elements in `list` with the same first and last item (Eg: `"Text"` and `"a"`), but I do not want to combine elements which meet some condition. For this example, I do not want to combine elements whose first item is `"TextElement"`. Thus, here is the expected output:

```
{{{"Text", "hello", "a"}, {"Text", " world", "a"}}, 
 {{"TextElement", "line", "a"}}, 
 {{"TextElement", "line", "a"}}, 
 {{"Text", "!", "b"}}, 
 {{"Text", "ok", "c"}}}
```

*Outline (for readability):* `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` → `{{1, 2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}`

I've tried the following code:

```
SplitBy[list, First[#] && Last[#] && ! (#[[1]] == "TextElement" && #[[2]] == "line") &]
```

It seemed to work at first, but fails the test above, as it combines the two `"TextElement"` elements. After looking at how the test function is evaluated, I can see why it doesn't work. How do I elegantly achieve the output above without resorting to loops?

Comment: Are they always sorted so that the elements you want to combine are next to each other?

Comment: Thanks, yes. Otherwise `Gather` or `GatherBy` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) might be easier to use here:

```
Split[
  list, 
  First[#1] == First[#2] && Last[#1] == Last[#2] && First[#1] != "TextElement" &
]

(* Out: 
{
  {{"Text", "hello", "a"}, {"Text", " world", "a"}},
  {{"TextElement", "line", "a"}}, 
  {{"TextElement", "line", "a"}}, 
  {{"Text", "!", "b"}},
  {{"Text", "ok", "c"}}
}
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Other formulations:

```
Split[list, #[[{1, -1}]] == #2[[{1, -1}]] && #[[1]] != "TextElement" &]

SplitBy[list, {#[[1]] /. "TextElement" :> Unique[], #[[-1]]} &]
```

Related: [How to Gather a list with some elements considered unique](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11448/121)